# SPOJ PALIN NZEC Error

Tags: java

I have used the following code for the question but it keeps giving me NZEC error when I submit it on SPOJ. My code runs perfectly on Eclipse or through cmd.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int line,num,numb,rev = 0,r,i,flag;
        ArrayList <Integer> nums=new ArrayList <Integer>();
        Scanner b=new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner a=new Scanner(System.in);
        line=b.nextInt();
        for(i=0;i<line;i++)
        {flag=0;
            num=a.nextInt();
            num=num+1;
            numb=num;
            do {
                while(numb>0)
                {r=numb%10;
                    rev=(rev*10)+r;
                    numb=numb/10;
                }
                if (rev==num)
                {nums.add(num);
                    rev=0;
                    flag=1;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {num=num+1;
                    numb=num;
                rev=0;}
            }while(flag==0);
        }
        for (int newnum : nums)
        {System.out.println(newnum);}
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont understand the changes you've made, I have just began using Java. Can you please explain or give reference to some useful resource.

Answer (score 1):

the mistake that you are doing is that you are storing `num` in an `integer datatype`..the constraint says that

> K of not more than 1000000 **digits**(it is `digits` and not up to that `number`)

It is impossible for an `integer` to store such a `huge number`..so you have to use `string` to solve this particular problem..try this input in your eclipse

> 454646546546546546546546464646464646

you will realize where you are wrong

Comment: Oh, so that means I have to transform the whole program from integer to a string. Even while checking palindrome I should not use mathematical approach but rather I should store the reverse of the string and then compare it to the original string. Is this approach correct then?

Comment: @yash10p :- yeah you have to use `string` and you can do it like that..there is also another approach..you can compare the `digit` at `first index` to `last index`, then `second index` to `second last index` and so on and if they are same then its ok otherwise it will not be pallindrome